# How to update multiple rows with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a site that has been attacked few days ago and that bad person took away couple of users emails and changed them. I need to restore as much as I can.

So I have two backups: after attack one and one from march.

I get whole lot of those emails like this

```
SELECT [email], [userId] 
FROM [lastBackup].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]
WHERE [email] like '%@dispostable.com'
```

The question is how am I about to update every row in my testing base which is under this condition to value from the `[oldBackup]` table.

I supposed it should be something like this, though it looks bad and doesn't work =)

```
UPDATE [testbase].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] AS tb
SET [email] = (SELECT om.[email] FROM [oldBackup].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] om
               INNER JOIN             [lastBackup].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] cm
               ON cm.userId = om.userId
               WHERE cm.[email] LIKE '%@dispostable.com'
               AND tb.userId = cm.userId)
```

Comment: What doesn't work mean? It throws an error or it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: It throws an error "wrong syntax near keyword 'as'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you got the form for the `update...from` statement wrong, try this instead (as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx)):

```
UPDATE [testbase].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]
SET [email] = om.[email] 
FROM [testbase].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] tb 
INNER JOIN [lastBackup].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] cm ON tb.userId = cm.userId
INNER JOIN [oldBackup].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership] om ON cm.userId = om.userId
WHERE cm.[email] LIKE '%@dispostable.com'
```